# Choosing the item located at the bottom

Tags: word-usage

There are 2 subway lines on the map parallel to each other shown horizontally. How to descibe the one which is below of another.

> You should take the line at the bottom
>
> You should take the down line

So confused. Thanks

Comment: I am confused as well. Are you describing the map or the reality interpreted by the map or both? Are the two lines actually parallel or only on the map? Does the map have only horizontal lines?

Comment: You, and the person to whom you're describing the route, are much better off if you say the "Circle Line" or the "yellow line" if it's color-coded. If the map is oriented to the north, you could say the southern line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should take the **lower** (subway) line.

as long as you are only referring to the position on the map.

*down* is a direction, not a location.

And while you could use:

> You should take the line at the bottom (of the map).

this means it is drawn at the bottom of the map, not its position relative to the other line.